# How can I make a buck-boost converter with a low-voltage cut-off?

Tags: buck-boost

I am in need of a constant voltage regulator to power my motors, as voltage will affect the motors' RPM. Although I could compensate via software, I would like to add a hardware deterrence.

My setup would be:

- A 7.4 V nominal supply. This is from two 18350 li-ions so 8.4 V at full charge and 6.8 V
- Four separate motors that at peak efficiency consume 0.5 A at 7 V

My target features are

- Output current of 1 A to 2 A (I could always use 2 or 4 if need be, of the same circuit)
- Can output a voltage of at least 6 - 9 V
- Can be made using SMD components :)
- Most importantly: a cut-off voltage

I have seen a good one from Pololu [here](https://www.pololu.com/product/2868) but I am going to do a single-board circuit. I have tried looking at what IC Pololu is using but I could not find it (I also doubt they will tell me.) I also tried searching, but I am quite overwhelmed by the extra specs manufacturer give (frequency, Iq, etc.) and don't know which one is for me.

I guess this question boils down to - can you recomend a good buck-boost converter IC that fits my needs and has decent documentation that contains a sample circuit in order for me to create?

Edit: Based on the chip and with the help of The Photon, I have made this circuit:

[image]

Comment: a zener, an opamp, and a fet should take care of you, no need for an IC

Comment: oh really can you show some example circuits? to be honest with you i am not good at using op-amps that why i tend to rely on ready made IC

Comment: @ThePhoton would you like to post that as an answer? i will look into it, it might take me some time to tell you if i will go with that IC

Answer (score 1):

> I have seen a good one from pololu here but i going to do a single board circuit. I have tried looking for what IC pololu is using but i could not find it (i also doubt that they will tell me).

FWIW, it looks like they're using [TPS63070](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps63070.pdf).

It matches the Pololu description in several points:

- Marked with "3070" like the device pictured on the Pololu website
- Comes in a 2.5 x 3 mm QFN-like package
- user defined under-voltage lockout
- 2 - 16 V input range
- Unusual pin arrangement with 3 pins along one edge with 4 pins on the opposite edge

Comment: Thank you very much,  May i ask. What do you mean by switch current? Is this the output current. And what am i expecting from the output of the buck-boost is it already a clean dc , or i still have to filter it out myself?

Comment: @Jake, that's the maximum current the switch inside the IC can carry. It will be the same as the inductor current. The rating has to be higher than the average output current because the inductor (and switch) current oscillates around the average current.

Comment: I see kinda misleading for beginners, Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: Also last question is it a good idea to place this near to each other? will the inductor not affect the other inductor? with this specs i might have to use 2 of them

Comment: Place what near each other? What other inductor? It will depend what kind of inductors you choose.

Comment: If it ends up that i need to make 2 of this circuits to provide power to the 4 motors, theres a chance that i will place this near each other (each circuit needs 1 inductor) . It seems that are smd inductor that are "shielded". Knowing that is still a good idea to place them a little bit apart

Comment: Yes, place them "far" apart or rotate one so they're at right angles to each other. You might also be able to use the SYNC feature to arrange the two converters to be drawing current from the upstream supply on opposite phases, reducing ripple.

Comment: Lastly sir, I am looking at digi-key. and there seems to be 2 version. with the difference of  _Output Current: 3.5A (switch)_ and  _Output Current: 2A_ what is the difference?

Comment: @Jakequin, notice some of them are adjustable output and others are fixed output.

Comment: I had already filtered out the fixed output,  here is a [link](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/pmic-voltage-regulators-dc-dc-switching-regulators/739?k=TPS63070&k=&pkeyword=TPS63070&sv=0&pv41=634&sf=0&FV=ffe002e3%2C1c0002&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=25)

Comment: @Jakequin, I think it's an error in the Digikey database. The difference between TPS63070RNMR and TPS63070RNMT is that one comes on a 330-mm reel with 3000 pieces per reel, and the other comes on a 180-mm reel with 250 pieces per reel. This info is on pages 35 and 37 in the datasheet.

Comment: Actually that is correct, i just filtered out the reel , Heres the [link](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/pmic-voltage-regulators-dc-dc-switching-regulators/739?FV=ffe002e3%2Ca4027a&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&k=TPS63070&pageSize=25&pkeyword=TPS63070) with the filters removed, but the difference is still there

Comment: @Jake, trust the manufacturers data sheet. The Digikey (or Mouser) database has lots of minor errors like that.

Comment: Hello , i seems cant find where/ how to implement the voltage lockout. which pin is responsible ? and How to set a voltage lock out of 6.5v for 7v,7.5v,8v. can you help me on this one?

Comment: @Jake, section 8.4.2 in the datasheet.

Comment: Got it, im assuming i can use pololu's formula for this one ?  EN/0.7v = Vin/Vcutoff

Comment: You would put a voltage divider between the input and EN, so that when the input gets to your cut-off voltage, the EN pin will be at ~0.8 V

Comment: oh i see it how it works now, its not in the drive IC but a clever use of components. What i have to remember is above 0.8v is fully on and below 0.6v is fully off ?

Comment: I have finished the circuit and posted it as an edit to my question, did i do it correctly  ?

Comment: If your question changes substantially, you should post a new question.

Comment: The Photon is bang on. Specifically tho the device they use is the TPS630701RNM fixed 5V version with marking 0701 as can be seen [here](https://www.exp-tech.de/en/modules/currentvoltage/8086/pololu-5v-step-up/step-down-voltage-regulator-s9v11f5)